# i'm trying to subscribe one device to multiple topics in flutter but it is not working

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to loop on listOfStringAnswers which contains list of strings , but when i debug it gives me exception : 'isValidTopic': is not true.

```
Future topicFunc() async {

  for (var element in listOfStringAnswers)
  {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(element);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please try to add additional details on what you have tried and why what you are trying to do is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved , i removed quotation marks from strings , after that it worked , because the string letters were surrounded with two quotation marks not only one quotation mark